# Sending Data to the external file

Tags: java

When your program is first executed, open the external file, read the data from it and place it in your array, then close the file.  Submit the external file with program.
To populate the external file for the first time, hard code into your program sending data to the external file.  You will only need to do this once - just when you've created the external file for the first. 
When the Exit option is chosen from the menu in the Driver, open back up the external file, save the array to the file, and then close the file.
One warning - do not confuse formatting the data for printing to the screen with how you format the data within the array.  When working with extracting data from an external file, you must save the data to the file in the EXACT same way you read the data from the file.

*** My Data is not saving to the file. Can someone point me in the right the direction Please. I need to send the data to the external file and some how its not sending the data there anymore. The programs runs but does not send the data to the file.

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Driver
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           //local constants
       //local variables
       String fileName = "items.txt";
       Scanner scanner = null;
       ItemsList itemsList = new ItemsList(5);
       int i = 0;
       int choice = 0;
       String itemName;
       String name;
       double price = 0;
       int qty;
       String cho = "y";

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    

    do
   {
       //Ask the user the following
       System.out.println("Menu");
       System.out.println("1. Add item");
       System.out.println("2. Display items");
       System.out.println("3. Exit");
       System.out.println("Enter your choice");
       choice = scan.nextInt();  

       switch(choice)
       {
           //Add an item to the itemsList
           case 1:
               //Ask user for to enter information
               System.out.println("\tEnter item name : ");
               name=scan.next();

               System.out.println("\tEnter price : ");
               price = scan.nextDouble();

               System.out.println("\tEnter quantity : ");
               qty= scan.nextInt();

               //Add the OneItem to the itemsList
               itemsList.addItem(new OneItem(name, price, qty));
               break;

           case 2:
               //print the list
               //print heading with specific formatter
               System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s\n\n", "Item","Price","Quantity");
               System.out.println(itemsList.toString());
               break;

           case 3:
               //Terminate the program
               System.out.println("Terminate the program.");   
               break;

           default:
               System.out.println("Incorrect option is selected.");
               break;
        }  
       //Ask user if they would like to continue
       System.out.print("\t\tWould to like to continue <(Y or N)> : ");
       cho = scan.next();
       System.out.println();

    }
   while(cho.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));


   //open the file and catch the exception if file not found
   try
   {          
      //create an instance of scanner
       scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

       //read file items until end of file
       while(scan.hasNext())
       {
           itemName = scan.next();
           price = scan.nextDouble();
           qty=scan.nextInt();

           //Add the OneItem object to the itemList
           itemsList.addItem(new OneItem(itemName, price, qty));
           i++;
       }

       //close the file object
       scan.close();          
   }
   catch (FileNotFoundException e)
   {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }

   writeToFile(itemsList);
}

  private static void writeToFile(ItemsList itemsList)
   {

   //Create a file name called items.txt
   String filename="items.txt";
   //Create a variable of Class PrintWriter
   PrintWriter filewriter=null;

   try
   {
       //create an instance of PrintWriter
       filewriter=new PrintWriter(new File(filename));

       //close the file writer
       filewriter.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
}


}//end Driver class
```

=========================

```
public class ItemsList
{
   //declare variables
   private OneItem items[];
   private int size;
   private int count;

   //constructor to set items, size and count to zero
   public ItemsList()
   {
       items = null;
       size = 0;
       count = 0;
   }  
   //Parameter constructor
   public ItemsList(int size)
   {
       items = new OneItem[size];

       for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
       {
           items[i] = new OneItem();
       } 

       this.size = size;
       count = 0;
   }
   //Add OneItem to the itemlist
   public void addItem(OneItem item)
   {
       if(items.length == count)
       {
           resize();
           items[count] = item;
           count++;
       }
       else
       {
           items[count] = item;
           count++;
       }      
   }

   //Resize 
   private void resize()
   {
       int oldsize = size;
       count = oldsize;
       int newsize = 2 * this.size;
       size = newsize;

       OneItem[] tempList = new OneItem[size];

       for (int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++)       
           tempList[i] = items[i];


       items = new OneItem[size];
       items = tempList;      
   }

   //getSize
   public int getSize()
   {
       return count;
   }

   //toString
   public String toString()
   {
        String description = "";
       for (int i = 0; i <count; i++)
       {
           description += items[i].toString();
       }

        return description;
   }
}
```

====================

```
public class OneItem
{  
   //declare a variables
   private String name;
   private double price;
   private int quantity; 

   //default constructor
   public OneItem()
   {
       name = "";
       price = 0;
       quantity = 0;
   }  
   //parameter constructor
   public OneItem(String name, double price, int quantity)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.price = price;
       this.quantity = quantity;
   }

   //toString
   public String toString() 
   {      
       return String.format("%-10s%-10.2f%-10d\n", name,price,quantity);
   }  
}//end of the OneItem class
```

Answer (score 0):

- writeToFile() is not writing anything to file.
- It is just creating an instance and closing.
- You can iterate itemsList and print each OneItem to the file, using println(OneItemObject) -- toString() should take care of giving what needs to be written to the file. (Almost pseudocode below:-)

  ```
   PrintWriter filewriter=null;

   try
   {
   // create a new writer
   filewriter  = new PrintWriter(new File(filename));

   //Iterate over items and print each item
    for(Item item: itemsList)
    {
     // print object
     filewriter.println(item);
    }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally
   {
   // close writer
   if(filewriter!=null) filewriter.close();
   }
  ```